# Why is eval not working with command substitution?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution, eval

I have this command

```
$("${DIR}/test.py" "$1")
```

the output of which is

```
export SOME_VAR="hello world"
export ANOTHER_VAR="hello"
```

But `eval $("${DIR}/test.py" "$1")`

seems to do nothing. What am I doing wrong?

I want to export those variables in my shell script.

Full bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash     
DIR="$(cd `dirname $0` && pwd)" 
eval $("${DIR}/test.py" "$2") 
exit $?
```

Python script (not full script but give a good idea):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3 
print('export var1="{0}"\nexport var2="{1}"\nexport var3="{2}"\nexport var4="{2}"'.format(string1, string2, string3))
```

Comment: It works for me... `bash-4.2$ ./x
export SOME_VAR="hello world" export ANOTHER_VAR="hello"
bash-4.2$ eval $(./x)
bash-4.2$ echo $SOME_VAR
hello world
`.   Note you shouldn't have the second `export` in the output, but it won't stop the code working

Comment: In total, i need to `export` multiple variables. For me it doesn't stop the code from working but it also doesn't export any vars to the environment. I tried using both `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/bin/sh` i am on bash3.2

Comment: Are you trying to export the variables to the current shell running the script, not just for the script environment?

Comment: @kevlinux yes, trying to export to current shell so other programs can use these vars.

Comment: the source python file these vars come from has these separated via `\n`

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]. Are you trying to export a variable to a parent process from a child process?

Comment: i will post the whole script.

Answer (score 2):

The example given works for me as well, but there is one potential source of trouble: depending on the values being defined, you may need double-quotes around the command substitution to prevent word splitting and wildcard expansion:

```
eval "$("${DIR}/test.py" "$1")"
```

Note that at the very least, not having double-quotes will cause troubles if the output contains multiple commands separated by newlines. That is because without the double-quotes, the output gets split into "words" based on whitespace (generally spaces, tabs, and newlines), and then `eval` splices it back together with spaces. Net result: all newlines get converted to spaces, and so all the commands that're supposed to be separate lines get mushed together into a single long mess of a command.

For an extreme example, suppose test.py outputs this:

```
# Define some variables:
export SOME_VAR="6 * 5"
```

The split-expand-merge process gives this resulting command:

```
# Define some variables: export SOME_VAR="6 file1.txt file2.txt otherfile.png 5"
```

(where "file1.txt file2.txt otherfile.png" are all the files in the current directory.) This isn't what you want at all.

Comment: thx Gordon. I will keep your tip in mind. The `eval "$("${DIR}/test.py" "$1")"` didnt solve it for me though.

Comment: posted full script

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not using `source` to allow exporting vars to the current shell.